# How to check if listbox2 contains some listbox1 items - VB.net

Tags: vb.net, process, listbox, contains, items

I have a program that check for current running processes and check if blocked processes are running if they do it will end them and ask for password to let you start'em so i added current processes to listbox1 and blocked processes to listbox2 now i want to check if listbox1 contains some of listbox2 items and get list of them and display it in listbox3 which is running blocked processes.
my current code:
listbox1 = crntprscbox
listbox2 = blockedprcsbox

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Processretriever.Start()

        For Each OneProcess As Process In Process.GetProcesses
            crntprscbox.Items.Add(OneProcess.ProcessName)
        Next

    End Sub
```

that's all i have right now
i hope i made my question clear if not tell me so i try to describe it more
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ. This example will find all items in `crntprscbox` in common with `blockedprcsbox`:

```
Dim result As List(Of String) = (From s1 As String In Me.crntprscbox.Items Where Me.blockedprcsbox.Items.Contains(s1) Select s1).ToList()

MsgBox( String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result))
```

Comment: well thanks for the answer it worked but when i replace `Msgbox` with `runningblockedprcsbox.items.add` it add them in one line , but i used the loop sentence and problem solved thank you ! ,
if anyone needs the code here it is :
`Dim result As List(Of String) = (From s1 As String In Me.crntprscbox.Items Where Me.blockedprcsbox.Items.Contains(s1) Select s1).ToList()
        For Each Process As String In result
            runningblockedprcsbox.Items.Add(Process)
        Next`

Comment: the msgbox code joins them all with Environment.NewLine. Glad you got it working